# SCVMM tfs task to restore to check point failure

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

We had SCVMM task in our release definitions in order to revert the snapshots, these tasks were working fine until the build agent was upgraded to version 2.112.0.

The task does not complete, the following message "Please wait Restore action is in Progress", seemes to be stuck indefinitely.

We have tried by creating new service endpoint following the instructions published here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/restore-vm-in-scvmm

Double checked all the user rights required to preform scvmm operations using tfs, still not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you share the detail release log on the OneDrive?

Comment: Try to setup a new build agent and try again to check the result. Note: Works fine for me.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Yes we can share the logs.

Comment: You can share the log files on the OneDrive.

Comment: On the other hand, try to add system.debug variable and set it to true, then create release and check detail log.

Comment: @starain-MSFT Please find the logs - https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aq5RIgsQvMcogSoon59QwsGsLA7r

Comment: What's the result if you run Get-SCVMMServer -ComputerName "JVSBANVMM01.jeeves.top" -TCPPort 8100 PS script from build agent machine? Can you reproduce this issue with another SCVMM?

Comment: @starain-MSFT We could resolve the issue, SCVMM connection from the build agents had issues, once this was resolved the snapshot restore task was successful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of the error was that the the build agents could not communicate to SCVMM server, this issue was resolved by maintaining the consistent SCVMM console version among build agent and SCVMM server.